# dplyr error rlang 0.3.0. Error in filter_impl(.data, quo)

Tags: r, dplyr

I updated `ggplot2`, `tidyverse` and `rlang` and now the function `filter` is not working any longer.

I get this error message:

```
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: `as_dictionary()` is defunct as of rlang 0.3.0.
Please use `as_data_pronoun()` instead.
```

Any idea what to do?

> version
>                  _
>   platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             darwin13.4.0
>   system         x86_64, darwin13.4.0
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          3.2
>   year           2016
>   month          10
>   day            31
>   svn rev        71607
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
>   nickname       Sincere Pumpkin Patch

Comment: Are you running with an old version of R for a reason (e.g., employer dictates updates)?

Comment: What code is causing the error?

Comment: Looks like you have an older version of `R`.  Please update the `R` and should work

Comment: @akrun Yes I was thinking of installing a new version but I am using some old packages for some statistical modelling and I am always afraid some old package won't run. Thanks

Comment: I would keep the older version and test it on the new version as well because you cannot keep on working with old version forever.  In this case, may be you have to install a version of rlang that is compatible with your R version

Comment: @giacomo: when you install new R version, the new libraries/packages will be installed in a different folder so there is no risk at all to try new R. You can switch between R versions easily within RStudio

Comment: ok thank you guys! (I like my old R packages ^^^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update only your `R` packages, you do not need to upgrade to new R version.

Issuing the next command `R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)` solved the problem for me:

`install.packages(c("BH", "bindr", "bindrcpp", "curl", "data.table", "dplyr", "evaluate", "highr", "Hotelling", "mime", "pkgconfig", "plogr", "quantmod", "R6", "Rcpp", "RgoogleMaps", "rjson", "rmarkdown", "stringi", "stringr", "tibble", "tidyxl", "TTR", "xts", "zoo"))`

(The package list was created by `RStudio` (I have updated all packages), but I think `install.packages("dplyr")` should be enough.